# WPML: hreflang is not implemented correctly

Tags: wordpress, wpml

I am using WPML for my multi-lingual wordpress site. I am having an issue getting the hreflang attribute to be implemented properly.

According to this article:
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en
The hreflang tag must include not only the url of the translated page, but also the url of the current page. For example, when I am on https://example.com the href tags should be as follows:

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://example.com" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="https://example.com/de" />
```

This seems to be the correct implementation, however when using WPML v 2.9 only the translated hreflang tag is displayed. For instance when I am on https://example.com it only shows the following:

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="https://example.com/de" />
```

I have ticked both options in WPML > Languages > SEO Options:

```
x Display alternative languages in the HEAD section.
x Add links to the original content with rel="canonical" attributes.
```

Perhaps I have misunderstood and having a canonical tag like this:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/" />
```

will suffice as the current page's hreflang tag. Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using WPML v3.1.8.4 and it's working fine for me. Can you try upgrading to the newest version?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this may be a conflict between WPML and another plugin - seems WordPress SEO. I saw it somewhere in WPML Support Forum

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Yoast Wordpress SEO and WMPL, juste add the following in your functions.php

```
add_filter( 'wpseo_canonical', '__return_false' );
```